# ReactJS обновление канваса после изменения состояния

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как можно поменять состояние в родителе и после его изменения изменить определенную часть кода в ребенкё?

Родитель

```
class App extends React.Component {

renderSettings(){
        return tooltip;
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        category: 'AreaChart',
        tooltip: <HoverTooltip
            chartId={0}
            yAccessor={ema50.accessor()}
            tooltipContent={tooltipContent([ema20, ema50])}
            fontSize={15}/>,
        color: "Light"
    };

}

handleInputTooltip(event) {
    this.setState({tooltip: event.target.value});
}

render() {
    return (
        <form>
            <div id="header">
            <div id="chartsType">
                    <select name="category" id="category-select" onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
                        <option value="AreaChart">Area Chart</option>
                        <option value="CandleStickChart">CandleStick Chart</option>
                        <option value="LineAndScatterChart">Line Chart</option>
                        <option value="Renko">Renko Chart</option>
                        <option value="PointAndFigure">Point & Figure Chart</option>
                        <option value="Kagi">Kagi Chart</option>
                        <option value="HeikinAshi">Heikin Ashi Chart</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="settings" value={this.state.tooltip} onChange={this.handleInputTooltip}>
                    <input type="radio" name="tooltip" value="Hover" checked={this.state.tooltip === 'Hover'}/>Hover
                    <input type="radio" name="tooltip" value="OHLC" checked={this.state.tooltip === 'OHLC'}/>OHLC
                </div>
                <div id="colorScheme" value={this.state.color} onChange={this.handleInputColor}>
                    <input type="radio" name="colorScheme" value="Light" checked={this.state.color === 'Light'}/>Light
                    <input type="radio" name="colorScheme" value="Dark" checked={this.state.color === 'Dark'}/>Dark
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="chartrender">
                <Area/>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
}
```

Ребёнок

```
class Area extends React.Component {

render() {
    var { data, type, width, ratio } = this.props;
    return (
            <ChartCanvas ref="newAppCanvas" ratio={ratio} width={width} height={400}
                         margin={{ left: 50, right: 50, top: 10, bottom: 30 }}
                         seriesName="MSFT"
                         calculator={[ema20, ema50]}
                         data={varnew} type={type}
                         xAccessor={d => d.date} xScale={d3.scaleTime()}>
                <Chart id={0} yExtents={d => d.close}>
                    <XAxis axisAt="bottom" orient="bottom" ticks={6}/>
                    <YAxis axisAt="left" orient="left" />
                    <AreaSeries yAccessor={(d) => d.close}/>
                    <MouseCoordinateX
                        at="bottom"
                        orient="bottom"
                        displayFormat={d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")} />
                    <MouseCoordinateY
                        at="right"
                        orient="right"
                        displayFormat={d3.format(".2f")} />
                </Chart>
                <Chart id={1}
                       yExtents={[d => d.volume]}
                       height={150} origin={(w, h) => [0, h - 150]}>
                    <YAxis axisAt="right" orient="right" ticks={5} tickFormat={d3.format(".0s")}/>
                    <BarSeries yAccessor={d => d.volume} fill={d => d.close > d.open ? "#6BA583" : "#FF0000"} />
                </Chart>
                {this.renderSettings()}
                <CrossHairCursor />
            </ChartCanvas>
    );
}
}
```

На место где "this.renderSettings()" в зависимости от выбранного radio мне нужно подставить определенный компонент (tooltip), либо тот что по дефолту, либо такой  и сделать обновление канваса уже с новым компонентом.

Как поменять состояние и передать его в наследника я понял, а вот как произвести обновление определенного места, не совсем понятно и вообще возможно ли это?

Comment: Ну так прокинуть ваше состояние пропсом в ребенка, в ренедре ребенка написать условие в зависимости от этого пропса. Реакт  не перерисует ВСЕ НАФИГ а посчитает какой кусочек пересчитать и перерисует

Comment: Соответственно кусочек в рендере можно писать тернарником в духе {this.props.awesomeTooltip ? <AwesomeTooltip/> : <DefaultTooltip>}

Comment: @Утка-Учится-Уму пропс - свойства, properties? А есть разница свойства это делать или через state?

Comment: да есть, здесь я могу только отослать к разделу документации который надо прочитать прежде чем писать что-либо на реакте: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё получилось)

Comment: @Утка-Учится-Уму, можно еще вопросик?)) У меня еще с помощью select меняется вид графика. Как вызывать разные компоненты, в зависимости от выбраного значения? Сейчас я вызываю ребенка прописывая его имя <Area />. А как вызывать разные? Не могу найти пример с таким синтаксисом. Пробовал, например, <{this.state.category} />, но так не выходит.

Comment: Не уверен что точно понял что Вы хотите. Вот это? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime. Возможно еще Вы ищете this.props.children или просто свитч в рендере функциональной обертки. А вообще для новых вопросов здесь принято задавать отдельный вопрос, вдруг новый вопрос заинтересует кого-то еще)

Comment: @Утка-Учится-Уму, сделал новый вопрос) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700136/reactjs-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0 . Я думаю тут немножко другое