# ReactJS вызов компонента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как вызвать компонент на JSX используя значение state?

У меня есть класс родитель, из которого вызывается компонент-ребёнок (вызов - ). Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой правильный синтаксис записи для вызова этого компонента, если его имя будет лежать в state. Например this.state = {component: Area}. А при вызове <{this.state.component}/> - не подходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSX тип не может быть выражением, а получение свойства объекта через точку - это тоже выражение.
Поэтому надо это выражение надо заранее вычислить и присвоить переменной. Обязательно с большой буквы (с маленькой буквы называются только заранее заданные теги).
Собственно прямо как написано в [**разделе документации**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) ссылку на который я Вам уже давал.

Что-то в духе

```
render(){
    let AreaComponent = components[this.state.component];
    ...
    return <Calculated>
}
```

сomponents - это множество в котором Вы ваши компоненты по имени искать будете. Они же не из воздуха берутся. И структура которая магическим образом соотносит js строчку с каким-то js-объектом (реактовским классом с именем совпадающим со строчкой) все равно нужна. Видимо ваше затруднение лежит в том где ее эту структуру взять.

То есть грубо говоря вам нужен объект вида:

```
let components = {
    'AwesomeComponent': AwesomeComponent,
    'SuperComponent': SuperComponent,
    'YetAnotherComponent': AwesomeComponent
}
```

Если Вы используете es6 модули и импортируете компоненты не одной пачкой, то склейка их в одну структуру ложится на вас, так как на текущий момент нельзя по имени обратиться к переменной содержащий весь скоуп модуля.

Answer (score 0):

Логика по клику кнопки, но могут быть и другие события:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
   showArea: false
  }
 }
 render(){
   let child = this._getChild();
  let areaNodes;
  if(this.state.showArea) {
   areaNodes = child;
  }
  return (
   <div>
    <button onClick={this._showChild.bind(this)}>Click to show child</button>
    {areaNodes}   
   </div>
  )
 }
 _showChild() {
  this.setState({
   showArea: !this.state.showArea
  })
 } 
 _getChild() {
  return <TestChild />
 }
}
class TestChild extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div>Hello</div>
  )
 }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но видимо я просто некорректно поставил вопрос. У меня будет например 5 компонентов с разными именами и select, в котором я буду выбирать необходимый. Значение из select будет записываться в state, а потом из state будет рендериться выбранное. Например есть компоненты Area, Line, Bubble - их вызов соответстенно <Area/> <Line/> <Bubble/>. А если будет записано в state -  Area, Line или Bubble, то как вызвать?

Answer (score 0):

Так в документации к реакту это расписано же. Имя компонента должно начинаться с большой буквы и не должно быть выражением.

```
const MyComponent = this.state.component;
return <MyComponent />
```